# Stop javascript increment at a certain value

Tags: javascript

I have coded this small script which increments a given value, in this case 200, by 1 every 3.2 seconds.

```
var i = 200;
function increment() {
i++;
document.getElementById('generated').innerHTML = Number(i).toLocaleString('en');
}
setInterval('increment()', 3200);
```

I'm trying to make the script stop increasing the value once it reaches a certain point (let's say 300 for example). I'm sure it's a simple fix but I can't think up of how to go about this.

Comment: Look into `clearInterval`.

Comment: var timer=setInterval(increment(), 3200); and use clearInterval(timer) to destroy the timer.

Comment: Like _j08691_ said, take a look at `clearInterval`. Additionally, you should never pass a string to `setInterval`. Instead of that you should pass the function directly as parameter: `setInterval(increment, 3200);`

Comment: clearInterval within increment function if i>200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var i = 200;

function increment() {
    if (i == 300) {
        // stop when it hits 300
        window.clearInterval(id);
        return;
    }

    i++;
    document.getElementById('generated').innerHTML = Number(i).toLocaleString('en');
}

var id = window.setInterval('increment()', 3200);
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to save the interval and then clear it:

```
var i = 200;

function increment() {
  if (i >= 300) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    return;
  }
  i++;
  document.getElementById('generated').innerHTML = Number(i).toLocaleString('en');
}
var interval = setInterval(increment, 3200);
```

Note that you can pass a function name instead of using the `"interval()"` string notation.

Here is a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/11fu5uuq/) (I've sped up the time so that it doens't take forever to prove a point)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could put it in IF statement as:

```
var i = 200;
function increment() {
    if(i<300){
        i++
    }
}
increment();
```

Comment: OP is using [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval). The answer is already given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28617394/4826457) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28617404/4826457). Your code isn't calling the function `increment` at all.

Comment: newbie solution : var i = 200;
    function increment() {
    if(i<300){
i++
}}; increment ()

Comment: You can use the [edit] link below your post to improve your answer

Answer (score -1):

You could use a for loop.

```
var i = 200;
var max = 300;

function increment() {

    for (i < max; i++) {
        document.getElementById('generated').innerHTML = Number(i).toLocaleString('en');
    }
}
setInterval('increment()', 3200);
```

More info here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp